# Specifying common fieldType for multiple classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap trying to set label width like this:

```
.col-md-12 label,input {
    width:38%;
}
```

To give the same value for multiple class, I tried:

```
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-md-12,
.col-lg-12 label {
    width:18%;
}
```

But it didn't work. What is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
.col-md-12 label, .col-md-12 input {
    width:38%;
}

.col-xs-12 label,
.col-sm-12 label,
.col-md-12 label,
.col-lg-12 label {
    width:18%;
}
```